# Namespace из корневой директории

Tags: php

Как мне можно указать namespace без привязки к корневой директории?
У меня сейчас проект лежит в www/ и namespace указывал www/Router;
Всё работало, но я хотел бы не привязываться к папке www
Пишу в файле Routing (namespace Router) потом в index.php пишу (use Router\Routing;), создаю объект этого класса ($obj = new Routing();), но пишет, что класс не найден.

Использую единную точку входа (index.php) и автолоад для загрузки классов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А ничего что вы пишете `use` раньше чем подключаете механизм автолоада?

Comment: Даже если я пропишу вот так(

require_once __DIR__ . '/logs/logs.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$obj = new Router\Routing(); )

Всё равно пишет:
 (Uncaught Error: Class 'Router\Routing' not found in)

Comment: _not found in_ где? Посмотрите в logs.php, возможно там стоит `namespace`, который перебивает ваш

Comment: _и namespace указывал www/Router;_ так корнем является папка www или www - это подпапка проекта?

Comment: Попробуйте в `use` поставить `\Router\Routing` с начальным слэшем

Comment: @СергейСушко, покажите из вашего `composer.json` настройки для `autoload` секции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по тому, что вы писали

> namespace указывал www/Router; Всё работало

Нверное у вас в автозагрузчике указан префикс пространства имен, проверьте свой composer.json там может указываться префикс:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"www": "../"}
}
```

Нужно убрать префикс

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"": "../"}
}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо.
В composer.json было прописано пространство не то что нужно.